# How to Run bash commands using cygwin in python

Tags: python, windows, bash, shell, cygwin

I am trying to access command line using following code:
os.system("cmd")

it gives me this error: 
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell

i can do all the cmd commands but cant do bash commands in this command line in python. though i have installed cygwin and outside python i can easily do the bash commands in cmd.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using mintty for cygwin instead of cmd?

Comment: Are you using cygwin python ?

Comment: @pak i installed cygwin for windows... I dont know about mintty.. im jsut getting the cmd in python but shell commands are not working inside python

Comment: @matzeri yes i have installed cygwin on windows and im using pycharm for python